# optional AND parameter in query

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to include a "AND" argument based on an argument? (Specifically, include a field in query only when it's NOT NULL). I'm trying something like the following

```
> WHERE something = something 
> CASE WHEN @param IS NOT NULL THEN (AND something2 = something2) END
```

...but I'm missing something
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
OneField = AnotherField
AND (@Param is null OR OneField2 = AnotherField2)
```

Just reverse your thinking about the null, you are asking for the field to null, or the other condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE something = @something 
 AND (something2 = @param OR @param IS NULL)